# First Day coding a VBA Macro: Why is my 2nd line showing as an error?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code from a youtube video I watched, but despite following the directions exactly my 2nd line of code keeps showing as an error when I try to run the macro?

-

```
Option Explicit

'early binding
Sub outlook_email_save()

Dim olook As Outlook.Application
Set olook = New Outlook.Application

Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
Set omail = olook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim ospace As Outlook.Namespace
Set ospace = olook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim myfold As Outlook.Folder
Set myfold = ospace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(Range("D2").Value)
Dim atmt As Attachment


For Each omail In myfol.Items

            If omail.Subject Like "*" & Range("A2:A519").Value & "*" Then

                    For Each atmt In omail.Attachments

                        If atmt.Filename Like "*" & Range("B2").Value & "*" Then
                            atmt.SaveAsFile Range("C2").Value & atmt.Filename
                        Else
                    'do nothing
                        End If
                    Next
Else
            'do nothing
            End If


Next



End Sub
```

Objective:
Download all attachments named "INVOICE CSF57796, INVOICE CSF56381, INVOICE CSF55242..." from outlook email with the subject line "Invoice.pdf" and store in a local desktop folder.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I would guess you've not added a reference to the Outlook object library in your VB project? (Tools > References)

Comment: @scottCraner I'm not really sure, but when I click run the macro it highlights "Sub outlook_email_save ()" in yellow and will not let me proceed

Comment: @TimWilliams I had "Microsoft outlook 16.0 Object library" checked before I wrote the code, but it will still not allow me to proceed

Comment: @ScottCraner more specifically it's a compile error: variable not defined

Comment: you have a typo here `For Each omail In myfol.Items`, `myfol.Items` should be `myfold.Items`

Comment: Ok, that worked. But now the debugger has opened and it's saying that this line is incorrect: Set myfold = ospace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(Range("D2").Value)

Comment: When you refer to `Range("D2")`, the program does not know where to look. Perhaps you can `Dim sht As Worksheet` and `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` then, you can refer to `sht.Range("D2")`

Comment: @Jessi OK, so how would that code look on that line? I'm sorry, but when I say today is my first day, I literally started learning how to write macros today.

Comment: I understand, @MattStapleton, Put the `Dim sht As Worksheet` and `Set sht= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` on earlier lines (like just before you `Dim myfold`). Then, just change `Range("D2")` to `sht.Range("D2")`. Note that you will need to make sure that where I have "Sheet1", you put the name of the tab that you want to work with.

Comment: Hmm, I think I added everything correctly:

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim myfold As Outlook.Folder
Set myfold = ospace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(sht.Range("d2").Value)

But I'm still getting an error on this line when I debug:

Set myfold = ospace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(sht.Range("d2").Value)

Comment: What is in "D2"?

Comment: @jessi "Billing" folder in my outlook email that I'm trying to extract the attachments from.

Comment: I recommend (for testing purposes) that you try `Set myfold = ospace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` and then make sure "Billing" is in there by `For each subfolder In myfold.Folders ` `Debug.Print subfolder.name` `Next subfolder` and you should see "Billing" in the Immediate window. Or, you can test hardcoding `("Billing")` in that line and see if it works. You may need to `Dim subfolder As Outlook.folder` first

Comment: OK, to clarify, should it look like this?

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("invoiceextract")
Dim subfold As Outlook.Folder
Set myfold = ospace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Billing")
For Each subfold In myfold.Folders
Debug.Print
subfold.Name
Next subfolder
Dim atmt As Attachment

If so, line 4 "Set myfold =..." has a compile error, "variable not defined".

Comment: You would want to do either or. So, either hard code your folder to Billing (inside inbox) OR set myfolder to inbox and have it print all folders. Essentially, I'm suggesting that you make sure that Billing is inside of Inbox in Outlook (or Outlook thinks that it is) because that is one potential error.

Comment: @jessi I got the debugger to go past `Set myfold = ospace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(Range("D2").Value)` by using `Set myfold = deffold.Folders("Billing")` but now the debugger has stopped at the 16th line. I've tried a bunch of different solutions, but nothing seems to wrk. This is what I have now `If omail.Subject Like "*" & (Trim(Range("A2:A519").Value)) & "*" Then` any suggestions??

Comment: What is in `Range("A2:A519")`? Excel is not likely to return a string here. You are saying, if the subject is `Like * ERROR *` and then nothing can work.

Comment: @jessi Email subject lines (i.e. Invoice CSF57796) I want the macro to reference in my outlook "billing" folder.

Comment: The issue is that the range is not a string. You cannot compare your email subject (a string) with `* ERROR *` because the range value returns a variant and not a string. You will want to replace that comparison to the range.value with a string - do something like (earlier) `Dim i As Integer, subs As String` Then, read in the subject lines as subs `subs = .Range("A2:A519").Value2` and you can (where you are trying) `For i = LBound(subs,1) to UBound(subs,1)` `If omail.Subject Like "*" & Trim(subs(i,1)) & "*" Then ` yadda yadda.